# Can't select array item from react props

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm having an issue with selecting an item in a stateless react component from props.

The general setup is very simple:

```
const useritem = {
  name: 'foo',
  images: [
    {url: 'urlstring1'},
    {url: 'urlstring2'}
  ]
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
    <User useritem={useritem}/>
  </div>
);

const User = (props) => (
  <p>{`imageurl is ${props.useritem.images[0].url}`}</p>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

see a working example at: https://codesandbox.io/s/9yk98okk64

I have a user object (hardocded as const useritem) with a name and an image array, containing two image objects. I'm passing the object as props to the User Component.

The part that is giving me a headace is:
 **props.useritem.images[0].url**
In the example above it is of course working. In my local environment it says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". So the images array seems inexistent, however I'm still able to access the equivalent of useritem.name without a problem.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could lie? As I said, the example above works in the codesandbox (as I assumed it would). What could be reasons it would break?

Comment: Looking at you CodeSandBox snipper i see "imageurl is urlstring1" so it seems ok... it's not helping I fear

Comment: Yeah that's the point. It works as it should but it doesn't in my app. It's a meteor app with react frontend. The most confusing part is that I can access "props.useritem.name" but I get an error with "props.useritem.images[0].url" -> so I also assume it's not a matter of the props not being passed down...

Comment: There are two things that you need to look into for debugging purpose. How is the component receiving the props(meaning is it coming from a async request) and second what is the props.userItem object that you are getting

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhatri . It was coming form an async request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this kind of issue when promises returns an nested object.

This might work for you:

`props.useritem.images ? props.useritem.images[0].url : 'loading...'`

This will check if the images property is there then get the URL otherwise show loading text.